# What are the options for registering address in Austria?

Tags: austria

My friend has a problem in Austria. Because of construction works he needs to leave his appartment as soon as possible.

My question is, what are his options? He is looking for something cheap (up to 300 euros), because he stays there only few days a month.

Is it possible to register an address at some kind of hotel/pension/motel? I researched this, but couldn't find anything conclusive.

Comment: I really hope this is the right site to ask this. I've seen similar questions. But if there is other place to ask this, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is he living in Austria? Or having to register for a long term visa? If so, it belongs on our sister site for Expatriates. I will move it for you.

Comment: A bit hard to answer with the current information. But in any case, you need to be aware that the registration is not (only) for having an address for eg. official letters, but to say where the *person* usually lives. If your friend needs an apartment only for some days per month, what happens in the other time? And what is/was the status of the old apartment (rented etc., and also just some days per month there)?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, and that's what he need an address for. He's lived most of his life there, but recently he's spending a lot of time in other countries. This is not relevant to the address thing, it's only relevant because it means that he doesn't want to pay a lot for an appartment. His old appartment is being renovated, which is emergency, and his land-lord has ordered everyone from the building to find a new place as soon as possible. Not sure if that's legal, but he says it is, because it's emergency.

Comment: Well then, it's certainly "possible" in theory to register the Hauptwohnsitz at a Hotel etc. - given that the company is ok with doing it the long-term rental way with all differences from a normal hotel stay. Proper contract, yearly BK calculation, giving "all" keys to the room, letting the person having own furniture, etc. ... basically, in the lower/medium price range such a hotel won't be easy to find. Getting some tiny old but normal apartment is easier and very likely also cheaper.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's mostly what I was looking for. You can add it as an answer if you want, so I can accept it.

Comment: I've just done so successfully with an airbnb host, but that was in Germany, not Austria.

Comment: @gerrit As the situations are still somewhat similar: I guess it's an apartment designed for someone living alone there, not a hotel room? Eg. own electricity and water amount counter, and so on. Then it's already easier to do, and more likely. And if the owner has several such apartments, probably some of them are already rented for long-term, meaning the process is not a new area.

Comment: He's resolved the issue, thanks for help. I hope this can help someone else too.

Comment: @deviantfan It has its own kitchen and bathroom, I don't think it has its own electricity and water meters.  But I'm not sure if either matters, surely people who rent a room in a *Wohngemeinschaft* are able to register there.

Comment: @gerrit I'm not sure why a WG matters :) Renting a WG is usually done as "normal" long-term rental with everything that goes with it. It's not comparable to the way hotel rooms are handled. ... Anyways, great OP has the situaion resolved.

Comment: @deviantfan I mean in a WG, one is not living alone, does not have own electricity and water counter, nor own kitchen or bathroom, so none of those are instrumental for being able to register — and at least in Germany, apparently some people do register at hotels.